# How to use jQuery code instead of EXT JS code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, extjs, extjs4

In my web application I have used EXT JS code.

Currently I am moving EXT JS code to jQuery code.

**Below is my EXT JS code, it contains form panel statements:**

```
    var signInForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.get('sign_In_Form'),
        labelWidth: 125,
        labelAlign: 'right',
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        monitorValid: true,
        defaults: {
            width: 200
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Email/Username',
                name: 'username',
                allowBlank: false
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'password',
                inputType: 'password',
                allowBlank: false
            },{
                name: 'test',
                value: 'testuser',
                xtype: 'hidden'
            }
        ],
        buttonAlign: 'left',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Sign In',
            formBind: true,
            handler: function() {
                if (processing == false) {
                    //some code here
                }   
            }
        }],
        keys: {
            key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
            fn: function() { // some code here }
        }
    });
```

I want to convert above EXT JS code to jQuery code.

Is there any guide available to do this....?

Your pointers are really helpful.

Thanks,

Pravin

Comment: Why do you need to convert to jQuery ? There is no auto converter, just learn jQuery and re-write your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raynos is right, you need to start reading the documentation to convert this code. Although it is not very hard to do.

If you are using EXT JS for a mobile app then you can use:

[senchalabs / jQTouch](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch)

Comment: Did he say it was a mobile application? Did you mean to recommend jQueryUI?